# creates a binary or combination of all attributes

Tags: python, django

I want to create a query that creates a binary or combination of attributes.

For example, I have the following class

```
class foo(models.Model):
    m_person= models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    m_rang = models.ForeignKey('Rang', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    m_a = models.BooleanField(default=True, name='a')
    m_b = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='b')
    m_c = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='c')
    m_d = models.BooleanField(default=False, name='d')
    ...
```

I am currently reading this class as follows:

```
obj = foo.objects.all().first()
attributes = [i for i in dir(obj) if i.startswith('m_')]

for tag in attributes:
    if hasattr(foo, tag.__name__):
         t = foo.objects.filter(person_id=aperson.pk, rang=arang).values_list(tag.__name__, flat=True)
         if True in t:
             do somthing
```

So I run through all the instances that match the person and the rank to then check the attribute.
I bet it's somehow more intelligent in combination.
I would actually like to read a combined "or" class from the database in order to process it further. instead of questioning each attribute individually...
since I need a or link, you could use first(value = true) somehow.

my wish would be something like this:

```
f = foo.objects.filter(person_id=aperson.pk, rang=arang).OR()
```

where the attributes then combine into something like this:

```
f.m_a = foo[0].m_a | foo[1].m_a | foo[2].m_a...
f.m_b = foo[0].m_b | foo[1].m_b | foo[2].m_b...
f.m_c = foo[0].m_c | foo[1].m_c | foo[2].m_c...
f.m_d = foo[0].m_d | foo[1].m_d | foo[2].m_d...
...
```

with:
`foo[0] & foo[1] & foo[2] & ...` element from `person_id=aperson.pk` and `rang=arang`

Comment: What should the type of `f` be in that case?

Comment: f ist a Instanz of foo, so f = foo()

Comment: and what to do with the other non-boolean fields?

Comment: ok, fair question. the fields person and rang would not matter. Should be divided into two tables